# Compare Traces with RML Utilities

Tags: sql-server-2012, profiler, performance, performance-testing

I am new to RML and am trying to use it to capture a trace, replay it on another server and then compare the two.

I have managed to capture a trace using the server side script that comes with it and then used ReadTrace to convert it to RML.

I have even managed to use OSTRESS to replay it on my new 2012 server named PROD using the following command.  I am only guessing this is OK being a 2012 server?

```
ostress.exe -i\\Path\*.rml -mreplay -c\\path\samples.ini -SPROD
```

While at the same time I had another server side trace running.

So how do I now compare the traces?  I have my first trace in a .trc format and .rml format and my second just in .trc.